# Different behavior when making CORS request using AXIOs (Chrome vs Edge)

Tags: rest, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, axios

I am getting a weird behavior from Chrome, which I was not recently getting.  A week ago, my project was making proper CORS requests to my REST api (Java spring) and all was fine.  But yesterday, Chrome (59.0.3071.115) is no longer sending the JSESSIONID as it used to.  It now sends a io cookie in its place.  That io cookie seems related to WebSocket in some way, which I am not making use of in any of my code.

The thing is, when I try the same code on Edge browser, everything is fine.  Edge does send my JSESSIONID cookie and no "io" cookie is sent.

Anyone has experienced this before?

Here is my setup and an example of a request on both browsers.

**Setup**:
OS: Windows 10
SPA: React, AXIOS (0.16.2)
REST: Java, Spring boot, Tomcat (Embedded)

**AXIOS configuration**

```
function getNewAxiosInstance() {
    //Init our instance
    const ax = axios.create();

    //Config defaults
    ax.defaults.baseURL = rootUri;
    ax.defaults.timeout = 1000;
    ax.defaults.withCredentials = true;

    return ax;
}
```

**Chrome request**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/api/2.0/client/service_orders/_activeState
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers
view source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3000
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Sun, 16 Jul 2017 13:58:39 GMT
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=6DA824C819AB48051DC6A63367010DDA;path=/;HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin

Request Headers
view source
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fr-CA;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:io=T6umtNN53FTADnx1AAAA
Host:localhost:8080
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36
```

**Edge request**

```
   Request URL: http://localhost:8080/api/2.0/reception/service-orders/_activeState
   Request Method: GET
   Status Code: 200 / 

 - Request Headers
   Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
   Accept-Language: en-CA
   Connection: Keep-Alive
   Cookie: JSESSIONID=177FD4191C578793F8BC04D9DB7287A5
   Host: localhost:8080
   Origin: http://localhost:3000
   Referer: http://localhost:3000/
   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36 Edge/15.15063

 - Response Headers
   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
   Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
   Date: Sun, 16 Jul 2017 14:08:26 GMT
   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
   Vary: Origin
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh well,

There was indeed something fishy with Chrome.  I just reinstalled Chrome from scratch and all is good.

Don't know what happened with Chrome, as I did not install any new extensions nor did I changed any settings.

Cheers